# Is our metrics and/or constants geocentric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, time, time-dilation, physical-constants

Considering that all our metrics is now based on physical constants as measured here on earth,

With earth having both gravity and velocity, as well as the whole solar system having too, and special relativity telling us that our perception of time changes based on those factors,

Will our metrics and constants have to be adjusted after we leave earth, or would aliens have to adjust our math to compensate for our perception of it?

Answer (score 1):

No, the constants are not frame dependent.

The speed of light is the same in every frame of reference.
In the same way, the exact energy difference in the hyper fine structure of caesium is fixed and so on.

Relativity maybe cause some small error in the measurement of those constants, but this can be neglected, since there are other experimental uncertainties .